# Export gridview data to xlsx format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a big gridview as part of a web application which has a combination of bound fields and template fields and has DataFormatStrings defined that define how values are represented on the cells. I am having a hard time converting all this to a datatable so that I can write them to an excel sheet.

Converting the gridview directly to excel forces me to use String Write and Html Write which produce only .xls format. We are looking at standardizing all excel download options to the .xlsx format. Here is what I tried so far

```
dt = gvInvoicesEX.DataSource as DataTable;
```

The DataSource property returns null for some reason. I have also tried the normal loop within loop technique to go over each cell in the gridview and copy it to the datatable but I just get a datatable full of blank cells.

```
for (int i = 0; i < gvInvoicesEX.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
     for (int j = 1; j < gvInvoicesEX.Columns.Count; j++)
     {
          gvInvoicesEX.Rows[i].Cells[j].Attributes.Add("class", "text");
          dr[j - 1] = gvInvoicesEX.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text;   
     }
     dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

The following is my excel conversion code:

```
using (var wb = new XLWorkbook())
{
    DataTable dt = GetDataTableFromGridView();
    string fileName = "BillingDetail" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".xlsx";
    wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        wb.SaveAs(ms);
        ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        ms.Close();
    }
    Response.End();
}
```

Is there anything I can change in any of the above to make this all work smoothly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really process the data directly from your source that feeds into your gridview, rather than trying to process the data inside the gridview and copy it back out. Gridview uses reflection and a lot of *really* high overhead processes, so by iterating and formatting directly from your datasource, you will skip a lot of that overhead and speed up your workflow quite a bit.

So with method you use to load data into the gridview, whether it's calling a stored procedure or whatever, you should load that data into a list of strongly typed objects and iterate over those to generate your excel sheet.

I would also highly advise, unless you're using complex formulas or similar in your sheet, to just allow standardized downloads as `.csv`. Excel will readily read that format, and it's much more open and easy to work with rather than using `.xlsx` drivers.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed response. Unfortunately restricting to csv is not a viable option due to the strict guidelines set forth by the users and also the gridview is not an optional step that I came up with.Users of the Web site are to be given the option of looking at numbers on the site as well as be able to download as excel.

Comment: Ok, in that case use the same datasource for your excel as you use for creating the gridview and your life should be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

### Gridview Export to XLSX:-

Iam using the library named EPPlus.dll for export .. Just download the EPPlus.dll from the link http://epplus.codeplex.com/ and refer the namespace as  `using OfficeOpenXml;` in your project.

```
   <asp:GridView ID="grdDisplay" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical"
                        OnRowCommand="grdDisplay_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" DataKeyNames="ID" OnPageIndexChanging="grdDisplay_PageIndexChanging"
                         PageSize="10" OnSorting="Sorting"  >
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#DDE8F0" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#DDE8F0" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black"/>
                        <PagerSettings Mode="NextPrevious" NextPageText="Next" PreviousPageText="Previous" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#DDE8F0" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
                       <Columns>
                           <asp:TemplateField>
                               <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgEdit" Width="25px" Height="25px" runat="server"  CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' ImageUrl="../Images/edit.png" />
                               </ItemTemplate>
                           </asp:TemplateField>
                              <asp:TemplateField>
                               <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgSearch" Width="25px" Height="25px" runat="server" CommandName="Search" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' ImageUrl="../Images/search.png" />
                               </ItemTemplate>
                           </asp:TemplateField>
                           <asp:TemplateField>
                               <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgHistory" Width="25px" Height="25px" runat="server" CommandName="History" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' ImageUrl="../Images/history2.png" />
                               </ItemTemplate>
                           </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="ID">
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="col2" HeaderText="col2" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="col2">
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="col3" HeaderText="col3" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="col3">
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="col4" HeaderText="col4" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="col4">
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="col5" HeaderText="col5" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="col5">
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="col6" HeaderText="col6" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="col6">
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="col7" HeaderText="col7" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="col7">
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="col8" HeaderText="col8" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="col8">
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="col9" HeaderText="col9" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="col9">
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="col10" HeaderText="col10" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="col10">
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="col11" HeaderText="col11" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"  SortExpression="col11">
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="col12" HeaderText="col12" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"  SortExpression="col12">
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="col13" HeaderText="col13" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="col13">
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="col14" HeaderText="col14" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="col14">
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="col15" HeaderText="col15" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="col15">
                                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            </Columns>
                              <EmptyDataTemplate>No Records Available..Please refine your search</EmptyDataTemplate>  
                    </asp:GridView>
```

**Button Export:-**

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnExportToExcel"  Text="Export To Excel"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnClick="btnExportToExcel_Click"    />
```

**Export Code:-**

```
 protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string mySqlQuery = GenerateQuery();
                List<Product> myGridData = GetGridData(mySqlQuery);
                grdDisplay.DataSource = myGridData;
                grdDisplay.DataBind();
                ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
                var workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Product");
                var totalCols = grdDisplay.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
                var totalRows = myGridData.Count;
                var headerRow = grdDisplay.HeaderRow;
                ///Ignoring the first three columns, Since first three columns are edit, search and history
                for (var i = 3; i < totalCols; i++)
                {
                    workSheet.Cells[1, i].Value = grdDisplay.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                }
                for (var j = 1; j <= totalRows; j++)
                {
                    ///Ignoring the first three columns, Since first three columns are edit, search and history
                    for (var i = 3; i < totalCols; i++)
                    {
                        var product = myGridData.ElementAt(j - 1);
                        string hdrTextVal = product.GetType().GetProperty(grdDisplay.Columns[i].HeaderText).Name;
                        if(hdrTextVal == "col5" || hdrTextVal == "col6")
                        {
                            workSheet.Cells[j + 1, i].Style.Numberformat.Format = "MM/DD/YYYY";
                        }
                        if (hdrTextVal == "col7" || hdrTextVal == "col8")
                        {
                            workSheet.Cells[j + 1, i].Style.Numberformat.Format = "hh:mm";                            
                        }
                        workSheet.Cells[j + 1, i].Value = product.GetType().GetProperty(grdDisplay.Columns[i].HeaderText).GetValue(product, null);
                    }
                }
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Product-Export.xlsx");
                    excel.SaveAs(memoryStream);
                    memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException exc)
            {                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }            
        }
```

**References:-**

```
https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/278/a-better-way-to-export-gridviews-to-excel
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it on a button click to export my gridview to xslx format. No need to fetch from datasource again. Just iterate through your gridview like

```
    protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (jvGrid.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Jv entries_" + cboQuater.SelectedValue +" qtr " + cboYear.SelectedValue + ".xlsx");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            jvGrid.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#fff");
            jvGrid.HeaderRow.Style.Add("color", "#000");
            jvGrid.HeaderRow.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");

            for (int i = 0; i < jvGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                GridViewRow grow = jvGrid.Rows[i];
                grow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                grow.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
            }

            using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                jvGrid.RenderControl(hw);
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }

        }
}
```

Please include the `System.IO` namespace in your code.

Comment: I tried your approach and got the error "Excel cannot open the file because the file format or the extension is not valid". Is it something you encountered too?

Comment: @Sai Nope. Do you have excel 2010 installed on your machine? This works good on my machine.

Comment: No, I have only 2007 installed.

Comment: @Sai This works for me with Office Standard 2010. Maybe the Response.ContentType is different for office 2007.